# Remove a specific checkin revision from SVN code

Tags: svn

Is there a quick way to remove a particular checkin from SVN codebase? For instance, my latest SVN revision number is 9999 and I want a code which do not have code checked in for revision 9978 & 9979.

This is how I am doing it right now:

1. Take the checkout until 9977:

svn co -r 9977 repo_path

2. Merge all changes until 9999 except 9978 & 9979.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [explained in SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo):

> **Undoing Changes**
>
> An extremely common use for svn merge is to roll back a change that
>   has already been committed. Suppose you're working away happily on a
>   working copy of /calc/trunk, and you discover that the change made way
>   back in revision 303, which changed integer.c, is completely wrong. It
>   never should have been committed. You can use svn merge to “undo” the
>   change in your working copy, and then commit the local modification to
>   the repository. All you need to do is to specify a reverse difference.
>   (You can do this by specifying --revision 303:302, or by an equivalent
>   --change -303.)

Use reverse merge:

```
svn merge -r 9979:9977 http://svn.example.com/repos/myrepo/trunk
```

Or use "cherrypick" merge:

```
svn merge -c -9979 http://svn.example.com/repos/myrepo/trunk
svn merge -c -9978 http://svn.example.com/repos/myrepo/trunk
```

After you are satisfied with changes done in working copy, do not forget to `svn checkin`.